# Spyder not recognising imported terms

Tags: python, numpy, ipython, spyder

I'm using Spyder 3.1.2 (Python 2.7.13). As part of the startup, the IPython console is set to "[Automatically load Pylab and NumPy modules](http://www.southampton.ac.uk/~fangohr/blog/spyder-the-python-ide.html#no-convenience-imports-in-ipython-console)".

When i want to use the method NumPy.zeros(shape), I can just call it in the IPython console as zeros:

```
In [12]: zeros(5)
Out[12]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

My problem comes when trying to call the same zeros function from a separate python file.

If I create a function UseZeros() in a file Test1.py

```
"""
filename: Test1.py
"""

def UseZeros():
    return zeros(4)
```

And I call it from a separate file, Test2.py:

```
"""
filename: Test2.py
"""

import Test1

testArr1 = zeros(5)
testArr2 = Test1.UseZeros()
```

In this script, testArr1 = zeros(5) works fine, but when calling Test1.UseZeros(), I get an error stating the global name 'zeros' is not defined.

> File "C:/Users/Gareth/Test2.py", line 8, in 
>       testArr2 = Test1.UseZeros()
>
> File "Test1.py", line 7, in UseZeros
>       return zeros(4)
>
> NameError: global name 'zeros' is not defined

Is somebody able to help my understand why when calling this function, the IPython console no longer recognizes the method?

The only reference I can find to a [similar problem](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2299) was fixed in a previous release, and was different to what I'm experiencing.

The reason I need this to work is that I'm importing functions used by somebody else who has made extensive use of commands such as zeros, ones, sin, cos etc., and I don't want to have to redefine everything.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder developer here*) The option to *Automatically load Pylab and NumPy modules* is provided to facilitate interactive work in the console but it's not meant to write code in the Editor because that code won't run outside Spyder.

I'm afraid to tell you, but what your colleague has done is a very bad practice and, in my humble opinion, I think the best you can do is to instruct him/her to fix this problem.

There's nothing we can do on the Spyder side to fix/improve this situation because we're not willing to promote bad practices, sorry.

Comment: Thanks Carlos, I appreciate the feedback. Will work on my colleague so we can switch to a more conventional way of structuring the work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for understanding, I know fixing this could take you quite some time.

Comment: Not at all, I was mainly concerned that I couldn't get to work, something that should. Happy to find out it's designed not to work that way :)

Answer (score 1):

As you use it, the `import` statement still has all functions and classes named within the module: `import numpy`, for instance, will allow you to access the `ndarray` class as `numpy.ndarray`.  If you want to import a given class or function into the top-level namespace, you'll need to specifically import it:

```
from numpy import ndarray
```

And if you're writing something small and aren't worried about cluttering the namespace, you can do this:

```
from numpy import *
```

In your case, with Spyder's automatic imports it seems to only affect the `__main__` level namespace, so you'll need to put proper import statements in any imported modules.

Comment: Hi Ben
Thanks for the reply. The problem is I don't want to have to modify my colleagues code. The problem doesn't seem to be the importing, but the redefining of functions for example, zeros=np.zeros, cos=np.cos etc.

My provided code works if you add zeros=np.zeros to to Test1.py

I was hoping there'd be a way to use his code without having to add all the imports and definitions, seeing as I can usually call the functions without specifying.

Comment: Do you know how your colleague has it set up?  In general, I'd recommend just calling `np.zeros`, it makes it clear where the function is defined/where to look for documentation.

Comment: My colleague has the same setup as me. But calls his methods from within the same python file. But I want to call his methods from my own python file, which is where I get the problem I demonstrated in my simpler example.

Comment: I don't think that it will be possible to do that unless you're calling from within the same python file.  If you're willing to let your code be un-maintainable, you could just copy-paste.  However, if you're sharing code like this you'll want to have a shared module that can be imported uniformly by both of you, otherwise you won't be able to maintain it over an extended period of time.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, for now I've copy pasted, but I'm expecting updates.
Part of the problem is even if I import the same libraries and definitions into my python file, the same error occurs.